# .htcaccess blocking cron request?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cron

I set up my IX Webhosting to conduct the following cronjob every 15 minutes.

```
usr/bin/wget -O- http://xxx.com/php/xxx.php
```

I want the php folder to be blocked off from all outside requests for security reasons, so I set the .htaccess file to deny from all. But when the .htaccess file is present the cron job is denied with a 403 error.

I thought that server-side cronjobs are not blocked by .htaccess? Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: On a side not: any reason you _need_ the webserver? I would say a `/usr/bin/php /path/to/greader_forceupdate.php arg1 arg2 etc..` would be a lot easier, and less error-prone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the cron job to:

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/web/root/php/greader_forceupdate.php xxxx
```

`/usr/bin/php` may need to be adjusted if PHP is installed elsewhere.
`/path/to/web/root` is the path on the filesystem.

To access the parameter, use `$_SERVER['argv'][1]`.

Comment: I looked into it and I think the problem is that the php binaries are not installed and I have to contact tech support. Thanks.

Comment: install the `php5-cli` package

Comment: Got it installed and working, thanks. For anyone else with IX hosting, php is now located at /hsphere/shared/php5/bin/php and your files are located at /hsphere/local/home/USERNAME/domain.com/script.php

Answer (score 3):

This is still a web request from localhost, since `wget` is a regular HTTP client requesting the page, and the web server is serving it (even though it may produce no output for humans to read). Instead of denying all, allow localhost:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add something like:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from 192.168.0.1/24
Allow from 127
Deny from all
```

in your .htacces to allow access from local intranet IP (192.168.0.1/24) and localhost IP i.e. 127.0.0.1